# having spacing issues in using "\n" in a separate file

Tags: python

```
e.write("y.write('\n+d')")
```

I was trying to write this line of code into a separate python program

```
y.write('\n'+d)
```

and when it wrote it, it went like this

```
str.write('

'+d)
```

but the '+d) was up one space above this text

any suggestions to keep it in the same line?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please format your question using Stackoverflow's tools. Also, can you write correctly your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.write("y.write('\\n'+d)")
```

(escape the backslash to make it a literal character), or:

```
e.write(r"y.write('\n'+d)")
```

(use a raw string to make backslashes not special).